# Latex glossaries: Hyperref/Link only the first occurance of an entry in each section?

Tags: hyperref, glossaries

By default, the `glossaries` package creates a link to the glossary for each occurrence of an entry (e.g. each time I use `\gls{entry}`). With the links visualized (e.g. using `hyperref` colorlinks). This becomes really cluttered if an entry is used many times.

I would rather prefer that only the first occurrence of an entry is hyperlinked. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While you can manually renounce the hyperlink by using `\glsentrytext{entry}`, or `\glsentryname{entry}`, or `\gls*{entry}` instead of `\gls{entry}`, this is cumbersome, as one would have to track the place of the first usage oneself.

An automatic approach is to patch `\@gls@`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
%% patch first occurence of "\@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\@glo@text}", as this is the one for \glsused{#2}
\patchcmd{\@gls@}
  {\@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\@glo@text}}
  {\@gls@link[#1,hyper=false]{#2}{\@glo@text}}
  {}{}
\makeatother


\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{pear}{
  name=pear,
  description={an oddly shaped fruit}
}

\begin{document}
\gls{pear}, \gls{pear}, \gls{pear}, \gls{pear}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

If you also use upper case variants `\Gls` and `\GLS`, the respective internal macros `\@Gls@` and `\@GLS@` need similar patching:

```
\patchcmd{\@Gls@}
  {\@gls@link[#1]{#2}}
  {\@gls@link[#1,hyper=false]{#2}}
  {}{}

\patchcmd{\@GLS@}
  {\@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\MakeUppercase{\@glo@text}}}
  {\@gls@link[#1,hyper=false]{#2}{\MakeUppercase{\@glo@text}}}
  {}{}
```

Comment: What about `\glslink{...}`?

Answer (score 6):

There's a hook `\glslinkcheckfirsthyperhook` that gets used by commands like `\gls`. It's original purpose was to assist with the opposite (don't hyperlink on first use) but it also can be used in this situation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*{\glslinkcheckfirsthyperhook}{%
  \ifglsused{\glslabel}%
  {%
    \setkeys{glslink}{hyper=false}%
  }%
  {}%
}

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}
\newglossaryentry{sample2}{name={another sample},description={another example}}

\begin{document}

First use: \gls{sample}, \gls{sample2}.

Next use: \gls{sample}, \gls{sample2}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document with hyperlinks for first use only]

*Edit:* This works for all the [`\gls`-like commands](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:gls-like) that query the first use flag (e.g. `\Gls` and `\glsdisp`). It doesn't work for the [`\glstext`-like commands](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:glstext-like) that don't query the first use flag (e.g. `\glstext` and `\glslink`).

Comment: What about `\glslink{...}`, `\Gls{...}` and others?

Comment: @patryk.beza I've updated my answer.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot is it possible to use this method also for section- or chapter-wise logic?

Comment: @languitar One possibility would be to hook into `\section` or `\chapter` etc to unset the first use flags.