# Glossaries: Hyperref/Link only the first occurence of an entry in each chapter

Tags: hyperref, chapters, glossaries

I want something similar to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109122/latex-glossaries-hyperref-link-only-the-first-occurance-of-an-entry-in-each-sec), but the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109137/31877) lacks a few things that I need:

- redefinitions of the plural variants of the `\gls` macros (`\glspl`, `\Glspl`, `\GLSpl`)
- every time a new chapter is started, I want the hyperrefs to be turned on again (automatically)
- in the `\printglossaries`-produced section, *all* glossary references should be hyperrefs (for when I'm using `\gls` in an entry's description)

Regarding the first bullet point, it would be nice if `\gls{x}` is the singular form of `\glspl{x}` would produce just *one* hyperref to the corresponding glossary entry.

An acceptable alternative to not having hyperrefs in subsequent glossary entry usages would be to just disable the colored boxes on the hyperrefs (but keeping the hyperrefs)

Answer (score 3):

If your `first` and `text` values are the same, you can achieve this using:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage
 [
    nohypertypes={main}% suppress automatic links for main glossary
 ]
 {glossaries}

% reset entries at the start of each chapter
\preto\chapter{\glsresetall}

\makeglossaries

% Modify the way `\gls`, `\glspl` (and their case-changing versions)
% and `\glsdisp` appear:

\renewcommand{\glsentryfmt}{%
  \ifglsused{\glslabel}
    {\glsgenentryfmt}% entry has been used.
    {\glshyperlink[\glsgenentryfmt]{\glslabel}}% entry hasn't been used
}

\newglossaryentry{apple}{
  name={apple},
  description={small round fruit}
}

\newglossaryentry{pear}{
  name={pear},
  description={small non-round fruit}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample}

\section{No Case Change}

Singular: \gls{apple}. Plural: \glspl{apple}.

Singular: \gls{pear}. Plural: \glspl{pear}.

\section{First Letter Uppercase}

Singular: \Gls{apple}. Plural: \Glspl{apple}.

Singular: \Gls{pear}. Plural: \Glspl{pear}.

\section{All Uppercase}

Singular: \GLS{apple}. Plural: \GLSpl{apple}.

Singular: \GLS{pear}. Plural: \GLSpl{pear}.

\chapter{Another Sample}

\section{No Case Change}

Singular: \gls{apple}. Plural: \glspl{apple}.

Singular: \gls{pear}. Plural: \glspl{pear}.

\section{First Letter Uppercase}

Singular: \Gls{apple}. Plural: \Glspl{apple}.

Singular: \Gls{pear}. Plural: \Glspl{pear}.

\section{All Uppercase}

Singular: \GLS{apple}. Plural: \GLSpl{apple}.

Singular: \GLS{pear}. Plural: \GLSpl{pear}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

First page:

[image: Image of first page]

Second page:

[image: Image of second page]

Glossary:

[image: Image of glossary]

If you have any acronyms then this method will reset them at the start of every chapter. If you don't want this to happen, then the code will require some modification.