# glossaries: hyperlink only at the first occurrence in every chapter

Tags: hyperref, glossaries, glossaries-extra

I am using `glossaries-extra`.

How can the hyperlink be suppressed after the first use of an acronym or glossary entry in every chapter (or section) without changing the first use flag? I have found [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129401/glossaries-hyperref-link-only-the-first-occurence-of-an-entry-in-each-chapter), which does not work with acronyms and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109122/latex-glossaries-hyperref-link-only-the-first-occurance-of-an-entry-in-each-sec/283573?noredirect=1), which provides a kind of hacky and ugly hotfix and another solution that doesn't work with sections or chapters. I don't want to reset the first use flag in every section/chapter to avoid repeating acronym explanations.

Is there a solution that is not a hack?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}
\RestoreAcronyms

\newacronym{ex}{EX}{example}
\newglossaryentry{foobar}
{
    name={foobar},
    description={The FOOBAR blaa},
}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

I explain \gls{ex} completely. But the second one here is short and has no more hyperlink: \gls{ex}.
Moreover, this is hyperlinked: \gls{foobar}, but this one is not: \gls{foobar}.

\section{Second section}

This \gls{ex} is short and with a hyperlink and this one is short and without a link: \gls{ex}.
\Gls{foobar} is linked, but \gls{foobar} is not.

\newpage

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aside: Don't use both `\RestoreAcronyms` and `\setabbreviationstyle`. Either use `\RestoreAcronyms` and use the base `glossaries` `\setacronymstyle` or use `\setabbreviationstyle` and don't use `\RestoreAcronyms`. (`\RestoreAcronyms` changes `\newacronym` back to the way it works with the base `glossaries` package rather than using `glossaries-extra`'s new abbreviation mechanism.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot thanks, seems this was a left over fragment from other experiments.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot do you see a chance to solve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `glossaries-extra` v1.26 (2018-01-05)¹ you can do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\GlsXtrEnableLinkCounting[section]{general,acronym}

% disable hyperlink if link count is greater than 1:
\renewcommand*{\glslinkpresetkeys}{%
 \ifnum\GlsXtrLinkCounterValue{\glslabel}>1
  \setkeys{glslink}{hyper=false}%
 \fi
}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym{ex}{EX}{example}
\newglossaryentry{foobar}
{
    name={foobar},
    description={The FOOBAR blaa},
}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

I explain \gls{ex} completely. But the second one here is short and
has no more hyperlink: \gls{ex}.
Moreover, this is hyperlinked: \gls{foobar}, but this one is not:
\gls{foobar}.

\section{Second section}

This \gls{ex} is short and with a hyperlink and this one is short
and without a link: \gls{ex}.
\Gls{foobar} is linked, but \gls{foobar} is not.
This link is forced on: \gls+{foobar}.

\newpage

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

This new link² counting method is independent of the first use flag so it won't interfere with abbreviations. The optional argument of `\GlsXtrEnableLinkCounting` is the name of the master counter (`section` in this case).

---

¹I've only just uploaded this version to CTAN, so allow a few days for it to reach the distributions.

²The term "link" refers to the underlying internal command `\@gls@link` that's used by commands like `\gls` and `\glstext` rather than to `\hyperlink` (which may or may not be used by `\@gls@link`).

Comment: That looks promising. I'll try one I get that version on CTAN.

Comment: Worked out perfectly!