# Using \hyperref and \ref inside see text of glossaries-extra

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

I have a working glossary for which I would like to use glossaries-extra (basically to have a link only in the first appearance of each glossary entry or acronym, such as in: [glossaries: hyperlink only at the first occurrence in every chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404051/glossaries-hyperlink-only-at-the-first-occurrence-in-every-chapter)).

However, in my glossaries I am using the see={} to add some more information, which may include hrefs, hyperlinks, and \refs.

When using the glossaries-extra package, this generates the following error:

```
! Use of \\glssee  doesn't match its definition.
```

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries    

\newglossaryentry{sample1}{name={sample 1},description={an example}}
\newglossaryentry{sample2}{name={sample 2},description={an
example},see=[My custom text \href{http://google.com}{Google}]{}}
\newglossaryentry{sample3}{name={sample 3},description={an
example},see={sample2}}

\begin{document}
\gls{sample3}. 

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

With the normal glossaries (\usepackage{glossaries}) everything works fine. Is there any way to achieve the same result I am having with glossaries-extra?