# glossaries-extra remove in-text hyperlinks after first occurrence

Tags: sectioning, glossaries, acronyms, hyperlink, glossaries-extra

Hi there while using `glossaries-extra`, I could benefit from the extra feature of having links for each first appearance of a new definition/acronym to the respective **Glossary** or **Acronyms** section. This automatically builds both sections so that hyperlinks to pages with further occurrences of either one of the two point to the correct place in the document.

However, for some reason I could generalize this only to chapter level. In other word, if a definition — or an acronym in my case — is used for the first time in another chapter the rule is broken and the hyperlink appears again but only for its first occurrence. I followed this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404051/glossaries-hyperlink-only-at-the-first-occurrence-in-every-chapter) to work through the process I just explained.

Now, my question is there is a way to suppress the hyperlink of additional occurrences after the first one at a global level over the whole document? If so I would be really happy to learn how to do so; my document is getting pretty big and I'm using several packages.
For this reason, momentarily I post the code block for the part that should do so in the preamble, but if anyone has any idea on how to solve this I can provide a more complete MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}


\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[postdot,acronym,toc]{glossaries-extra}

%GLOSSARY TERMS AND ACRONYMS
\makeglossaries
\GlsXtrEnablePreLocationTag{Page: }{Pages: }
\GlsXtrEnableLinkCounting[chapter]{general,acronym}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\makefirstuc{#1}} % capitalize the entry in the glossary
\renewcommand*{\acrshort}[1][]{\glsxtrshort[#1]} % required for glossaries-extra functionalities
\renewcommand*{\acrshortpl}[1][]{\glsxtrshortpl[#1]} % required for glossaries-extra functionalities
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\color{black}{#1}} % required for glossaries-extra black in-text links
% disable hyperlink if link count is greater than 1:
\renewcommand*{\glslinkpresetkeys}{%
 \ifnum\GlsXtrLinkCounterValue{\glslabel}>1
  \setkeys{glslink}{hyper=false}%
 \fi
}

%EXAMPLE TERMS
\newglossaryentry{graph-topology}
{
    name=topology,
    description={collection of features and properties describing a graph data structure}
}

\newacronym{hifi}{HiFi}{High Fidelity, same as CCS}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

The assemblies for these individuals were generated from \acrshort{hifi} long reads in combination with long-range contact information from parental data through trio binning <citation> of short reads. Beyond the purpose of the text above, I'm using here the \gls{graph-topology} terms which since it has been used only once, it appears in the Terminology section.

\chapter{Results}

I computed the following assembly statistics for individuals: HG002, HG00514, HG00733, HG03492 and NA19240 with \texttt{gfastats v1.3.0} <citation> as per \dots. Aside from individual HG002 with a \acrshort{hifi} coverage in folds of $\sim$130× and sequenced with a 20Kbp \acrshort{hifi} chemistry, other individuals show values in line with those of assemblies, produced from long reads \acrshort{hifi} data and long-range Hi-C contact information, which did not underwent ulterior polishing and curation. The average coverage for the \acrshort{hifi} datasets varied from a maximum of $\sim$76× to a minimum of $\sim$34×.

As in the previous chapter, I'm here using the \gls{graph-topology} terms which appears to have the same issue despite the settings used in the preamble.

\printglossary[title=Terminology, toctitle=Terminology]

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=List of Abbreviations, toctitle=List of Abbreviations]

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

Quick update, it appears to be happening only for acronyms upon a more in-depth inspection.

**NEW**

I was wrong working on a MWE highlighted the issue also for glossary entries...

Comment: I don't even start to think about such a question if there is no full example that can be used for test.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you're right sorry. I think was very out of context, I added a MWE and indeed it has been very useful. The problem is pervasive and affects also glossary entries. Do you know how to address it? Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer let me know whether the MWE works for you. I'm happy to provide extra context if helps!

Comment: well you are resetting the link counter by chapter with `\GlsXtrEnableLinkCounting[chapter]{general,acronym}`, so naturally it restarts on a new chapter, remove the `[chapter]` if you don't want that.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer oh such a stupid mistake, sorry... I though I should have set it to a level above the `[chapter]` but I didn't know which one. Now, is working as expected; however, it is worth noting in my "erroneous" version the behavior was somehow inconsistent. For instance, in the MWE above the links reappear for both glossary and acronyms entries whereas in my whole big document the problem is restricted to only acronyms. I can confirm that as I double-checked multiple times; I don't know why though...