# Hyperref/link only first the first acronym of an entry on a site

Tags: hyperref, acronyms

I'm using the package `acronym` for acronyms . In combination with the `hyperref` package, all acronyms are linked to the acronym list.
Now I'm using some acronyms more then one time on one page. Is it possible to configure `acronym` in a way that only the first acronym is linked to the acronym list?

I found something familiar but it's for glossary and I can't get it work for acronym:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109137/71159

Comment: A starter document would be nice!

Comment: First ever or first use on a page?  Either way, to automate the process you could use the xstring package to create a delimited list of acronyms and check if a particular acronym is on the list.

Comment: The way acronyms are managed is very well established, and implemented in related packages like `acronym` and `glossaries`. I do not see reasonable advantages in deviating from that.
From your question, I understand that, if a given acronym appears on several pages and several times on each page, the first occurrence (and only the first one) of that acronym on _each_ page should be hyperlinked.
Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command of the linked answers (`\glsentrytext{entry}`) for acronyms, too.

Unless you are bounded to the `acronym` package for some specific reason, you can use the `glossaries` package for you acronyms and take advantage of `\glsentrytext{entry}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=List of acronyms]
\newacronym{tag}{ACR}{ACRonym definition}
some text
some text
\gls{tag} % first time on the page
some text
some text
\glsentrytext{tag} % every other time you want
\end{document}
```

However, I'm not sure how you can detect when a given occurrence of the acronym is the first one on a given page.