# glossaries package: hyperlink only on first use of acronym

Tags: hyperref, glossaries, links

I use the glossaries package to define and use acronyms in my text. I use `\newacronym{}` to define my acronyms. In the text I use `\gls{}` to refer to these acronyms.

In order to improve readibility of my text, I only want a link from the acronym to the glossary-entry on first use. For some acronyms which are used extensively in my text, it would not look nice, if at each use of the acronym a hyperlink appears in the PDF.

Hence, I would like to know how I can achieve this behavior: link to the glossary only for the first use of an acronym.

In the user manual of the glossaries package, there seems to be a parameter doing exactly that: `hyperfirst`. However, if I set it to true (default is true anyway), I still have link at all acronym usages (i.e. `\gls{}`) throughout the document.

**EDIT:**

Ohps, just found the solution here: [Latex glossaries: Hyperref/Link only the first occurance of an entry in each section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109122/latex-glossaries-hyperref-link-only-the-first-occurance-of-an-entry-in-each-sec)

should we delete or mark as duplicate?

Comment: Delete it -- you can do it yourself ;-)

Comment: but maybe having the duplicate increases the chance that people stumble upon it while google'ing, ultimately supporting to solve same problems in future... so maybe just keeping it and having it marked as a duplicate is the better solution.